# Reading txt file with fscanf( Problems with fscanf reading strings line by line)

Tags: c, string, file-io, scanf, whitespace

```
Contents of input.txt:
Xanthos
Myra
Phaselis
Contents of input2.txt:
askjdkdanmowflfkadkjkaksdklskksadllasd
fkfklsal;sdlslfsdkdfkMyraslfsfeokdlasdfdf
wfewfPsdflsdfklsdosfkeowkfweofkwoefkkfsf
sdfsdakjewofksdfoiwefjowefks;dfPhaselissdfkefowefjksdlfjslfjsldfj
oefkwtifjslflsdfkjeifjsl;asldkiefjiefjlskfdjeifjksk
output.txt:Xanthos(8,9)
 Myra(2,22)
 Phaselis (4,32)
```

I wrote a program that searches for the string inside the input at input 2, finds its location and writes it to the  output. It prints only the position of the first string(Xanthos (8,9).Could the problem be related to whitespaces?Expected output.txt as above, but the output I received only has Xanthos (8,9).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE_2 150

int indexOfhor(FILE *fptr, const char *word, int *line, int *col);
int main(){
    FILE *fptr;
    FILE *fptr1;
    FILE *fptr2;
    int line ,col;

    char word[10];
    fptr = fopen("input.txt","r");
    fptr1= fopen("input2.txt", "r");
    fptr2= fopen("output.txt","a"); 
       while (fscanf(fptr, "%s", word) != EOF ) {
             //rewind(fptr1) after adding this problem is solved
             indexOfhor(fptr1, word, &line, &col );
             if(line != -1 ){
                        fprintf(fptr2,"%s (%d,%d)\n", word, line + 1, col + 1);
              }
             else if(line==-1) continue;;
        }
    fclose(fptr);
    fclose(fptr1);
    fclose(fptr2);
    return 0;
}
int indexOfhor(FILE *fptr, const char *word, int *line, int *col){
    char str[BUFFER_SIZE_2];
    char *pos;
    *line = -1;
    *col  = -1;

    while ((fgets(str, BUFFER_SIZE_2, fptr)) != NULL)
    {
        *line += 1;
         pos = strstr(str, word);
         if (pos != NULL){
            *col = (pos - str);
            break;
        }
    }
    // If word is not found then set line to -1
    if (*col == -1)
        *line = -1;
    return *col;
}
```

Comment: See http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfinterlace.html I suspect you're running into that problem.

Comment: After calling `indexOfhor` the `fptr1` is pointing to the end of the file. Need to `rewind(fptr1)`.

Comment: @Shawn 
I don't know just the first string seems to be retrieved by the function but the others (Myra and
Phaselis) is not sent to the function so I thought the problem was in the fscanf part

Comment: @kaylum Every time I run it even if I  rewind(fptr1), it only prints Xanthos (8,9) again at the end of the output. There must be another error

Comment: Have you actually tried to debug it? Does `indexOfhor` get called with the right words? Does the `fgets` in that function read the right lines? etc. You should have answers to all these questions and can get that with a debugger.

Comment: @kaylum 
Yes I tried, I had no problem when I got the word from the user, not the input, but I have a problem when I get it from the file. The reason I asked the question is that I could not find the wrong part of this code..

Comment: So where did you find things start going wrong? What are the answers to the specific questions I asked for example? *Does indexOfhor get called with the right words? Does the fgets in that function read the right lines?*. Answers for the code that reads from file not answers for manual user input.

Comment: @kaylum  Does indexOfhor get called with the right words and Does the fgets in that function read the right lines??
Both yes I can't see an error. If there is an error, the word searched in the file would not work if it was not taken from the file but from the user.So where did you find things start going wrong?
I get the wrong output even though I think I did everything right lol.

Comment: I think you are confusing *testing* and *debugging*. Testing is simply plugging in input and checking the result. So it's a pass/fail thing. Debugging means stepping through the code line by line and matching the behaviour/result of every line with what you think it should be. Then finding which exact line of code does not behave as expected - does not have the right value, does not go into the right code block, etc.

Comment: And where did you put the `rewind` call? Please update the code with that because that is certainly an error and the code cannot possibly work without that.

Comment: @kaylum 
Thank you very much rewind was inserted in the wrong place (I added it inside the if block before) I would have an irrelevant question, do you think it makes sense to do the following function modified vertical word search without writing new code?

Comment: I don't understand what "vertical word search" means.

Comment: Some words in the file are positioned vertically rather than horizontally like a puzzle game.p\nl\na\ny.There i have word"play."But comment section is no let me position it vertically xd